# weak property conforming to protocol with generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I wrote simplified version of similar implementation I'm having problem with. Anyone knows why is that and eventually how to workaround?

NOTE: the code is just example to keep it as simple as possible

```
protocol Alertable {
   associatedtype Alert

   func show(alertOfType alertType: Alert)
}
```

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: class, Alertable {
}

final class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   // MARK: - Types

   enum AlertType {
      case alert
      case warning
   }
}

extension MyViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {
   typealias Alert = AlertType   // ! here i specify the associated type !

   func show(alertOfType alertType: Alert) {
      // code..
   }
}
```

So far so good. But, here I get errors:

```
final class ViewModel {

   // ERROR: Protocol 'ViewControllerDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.
   weak var viewController: ViewControllerDelegate?

   init(viewController: ViewControllerDelegate?) {
      self.viewController = viewController
   }

   private func someFunction() {

      // ERROR: Member 'show' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'NewsFeedViewControllerInput'; use a generic constraint instead.
      viewController?.show(alertOfType: .warning)

      // code..
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The error is self explanatory. You can't use `ViewControllerDelegate` or `Alertable` until you specify the `associatedtype`. Btw, is it really necessary to have a generic type on `Alertable`? I think you can better change that to concrete type `AlertType`. If you really need it as generic then i would suggest reading [type erasure](https://medium.com/swiftworld/swift-world-type-erasure-5b720bc0318a).

Comment: Seems you already use a concrete implementation of `ViewControllerDelegate`, by passing `.warning` to `show(alertOfType:)`, you might as well replace `ViewControllerDelegate` by `MyViewController`.

Comment: @Kamran: I specified associated type in `MyViewController`s extension by `typealias Alert = AlertType`. 

It's just example - I do something different in real code, but the principle is 100% same. I wanted the example to be simple as possible.

Comment: @Cristik: The purpose of `ViewControllerDelegate` is to expose only that functions that we want to allow ViewModel to call. I don't want to allow `ViewModel` to do anything else. 
I chose bad name for the delegate. It should be `MyViewControllerDelegate`.

Comment: @Lachtan Yes, that's why you are not getting any error in `MyViewController`. Error is inside `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a bit of a misunderstanding here. When you define:

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: class, Alertable {}

extension MyViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {
    typealias Alert = AlertType   // ! here i specify the associated type !

    func show(alertOfType alertType: Alert) {
        // code..
    }
}
```

The typealias is defined in `MyViewController` but not `ViewControllerDelegate`. It's not clear why you need `ViewControllerDelegate` in this question but maybe there's something we don't see in the real app.

In `ViewModel`, change from `ViewControllerDelegate` to `MyViewController`:

```
final class ViewModel {
    weak var viewController: MyViewController?
    // ...
}
```

---

One more thing, though unrelated to the error: you use many `final class`es. Should they be `struct`s instead?

Comment: You are correct. I don't think there is any workaround this. Thank you